# Selecting an appropriate dialog for user defined installation

Tags: xml, wix, wix3.5

I have a project in which i have the following files

```
main.wxs - directory structure
MyInstallDirDlg.wxs - for selceting the path of installation 
MyWixUI_InstallDir.wxs - define the UI
```

I want the installer to work in the following ways:

after the license agreement is signed , it should check for type of install default or advanced , so i need to insert a dialog in which there should be two radio buttons -

one for default and another one for advanced and once default is selected and i click on next it should proceed to the InstallDirDlg for the next steps of installation.let me know how to do this and select the appropriate dialog

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the [WiX Tutorial](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial), in particular

- [UI Wizardry](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/user-interface/ui-wizardry),
- [New Link in the Chain](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/user-interface/new-link-in-the-chain), and
- articles in [User Interface Revisited](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/user-interface-revisited) section.